# How to only show fixed effect estimates of lmer model using sjPlot::plot_model

Tags: r, lme4, sjplot

I would like to plot the estimates of the fixed effects of an lme4::lmer model. Currently, the sjPlot::plot_model output includes two additional plots that I do not want: SD (Observations) and SD (Intercept). How can I remove these two additional plots?

```
library(lme4)
data(iris)
lmerMod <- lmer(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width * Petal.Length + (1|Species), data=iris)

library(sjPlot)
plot1 <- plot_model(lmerMod,
           type = "est",
           show.intercept = TRUE,
           title = "Estimates of fixed effects")
```

[plot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXpBa.png)

Essentially, I would like an output that looks like what is produced when plotting the fixed effects of an glm model, e.g.:

```
glmMod <- glm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width * Petal.Length, data=iris)
plot2 <- plot_model(glmMod,
           type = "est",
           show.intercept = TRUE,
           title = "Estimates of fixed effects")
```

[plot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FWya.png)

I believe that this what the sjPlot::plot_model function used to produce by default when plotting lmer models before because this is what my code used to produce. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried reinstalling all the packages and restarting your RStudio session? It's possible that you overwrote some sort of default because I can't reproduce the images that you have attached. I'm using the most recent version of sjPlot from CRAN (2.8.9).

This is what I get when I run your code, slightly modified to call the plot to plot window:

```
library(lme4)
data(iris)
lmerMod <- lmer(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width * Petal.Length + (1|Species), data=iris)

library(sjPlot)
plot1 <- plot_model(lmerMod,
           type = "est",
           show.intercept = TRUE,
           title = "Estimates of fixed effects")
plot1
```

[image]

And then I run the second part:

```
glmMod <- glm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width * Petal.Length, data=iris)
plot2 <- plot_model(glmMod,
                    type = "est",
                    show.intercept = TRUE,
                    title = "Estimates of fixed effects")
plot2
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I had already tried restarting my R session several time but reinstalling the ```sjPlot```package did the trick!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it's sorted!